# Does Individuals saving adversely effect the economy of a country?

Tags: economy

Does decision of Individuals to save money affect the economy of a country negatively? I think so yes, because if a high earning individual refuses to spend money then it stop the 'gears' of the economy from turning.

Comment: Saving equals investing and for example the Chinese have a relatively high saving rate. Didn't hurt them so far, rather helped them.

Comment: I think this would receive better answers on [Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on the **scale** of the saving practices across society.

If too many people are spending money, then it might lead to inflation. If too many people are saving money, then it might lead to deflation. This only happens if the whole society is doing it at a large scale, a single person is unlikely to make either scenario happen even if they are very rich.

Additionally - to make the answer relevant to Politics Stack - I would not impose individual responsibility on people to keep the economy running. They are free to save or spend their income as they wish, that's the main pillar of a market economy. So how do you keep the economy healthy? Well the government actually has its own political tools to ["heat up" or "cool down"](https://youtu.be/VvgVHUzBCuY) the economy via Central Bank.

For example, in Japan, saving is a big thing culturally so the government really needs to encourage people to spend more. Incoming [Abenomics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abenomics) which attempted to address this problem.

An opposite example, in United States, spending is the big thing culturally which led to endemic inflation (prices keep going up too fast). So President Jimmy Carter nominated a central banker called Paul Volcker who famously [hit a break on economy](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/16/podcasts/the-daily/inflation-interest-rates-fed-volcker.html) to discoruage people to spend money. The short-term pain was acute but it did stop inflation.

**TLDR: Saving or spending is a personal choice. A healthy economy wants people to do both, but not too much in either direction. The government has the tools to steer the economy in either direction so there's really no point to impose individual responsibility on people to save or spend.**